# Logic to test that 2 out of 4 are true

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, booleanquery

The closest I have got is (((A ↮ B) ∧ (C ∧ D)) ⊽ ((A ∧ B) ∧ (C ↮ D))), but when all 4 are true then the output is true and I don't want that. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

For "1 or 2 out of 4 inputs true", the minimized sum of products form is:

```
 F = A' B C'  + A B' C'  + A' B' D + A B' D' + A' C D' + A C' D';
```

A multi-level solution:

[image]

---

For "exactly 2 out of 4 are true", a minimized sum of products form:

```
F = A' B' C D + A' B C' D + A B' C' D + A' B C D' + A B' C D' + A B C' D'
```

A multi-level circuit:

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you for answering but i needed it to be 1 or 2 is true, 3 and 4 is false if you get me. Btw thank you again <3

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 of four inputs can be true. The output is true, if 1 or 2 inputs are true?

Comment: if 1 and 2 are true then output is true, if 1, 2 and 3 are true then output is false, same witha all 4 if true. ! and 2 true output true, if true=>3 then false. I hope you understand it better. Ty.